# Charts in Joomla Site or Modules

Tags: joomla, module, charts

I have a joomla site and I would to know if it is possible to integrate your charts inside articles or modules?

Comment: wht you mean by charts ? Graphical report (http://www.fusioncharts.com/) then you can create module for that and use it on article or module itself .

Comment: I mean a chart like this one: http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#line-and-area

Comment: How can i intregate it in my Joomla site?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate any of the charts from fusionchart.com in joomla you can just download the package and integrate it with pure php. The you can simply follow the module structure of joomla [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5).

the advantage of using module in joomla you can use that in various places and multiple time with a page. 
Also you can use that module inside your article too.
 for [more](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article?)

Hope this may help you..

Comment: And did you know what is the price? I read 2,990 Dollars... is possible?

Comment: the free version available with limited features..that will works fine.I used that for an application long before now also its fine